# python3 sqlite3 unable to open database in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, sqlite

I am unable to create a database file using python. I am facing this issue only in windows. On my Mac machine i was able to get it working. Here is a test code i tried -

```
import os, sys, shutil, glob, pandas, sqlite3

db_path = 'E:\\Archive.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
```

Here are other versions of variable db_path i have tried

```
db_path = 'E:\Archive.db'

db_path = 'E:/Archive.db'

db_path = 'E://Archive.db'
```

But i always get following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I do have write permissions on E: 
I was able to create csv files using python script. Not sure why its stuck with database. It should create the database in E:

Comment: Often you don't have permission to create files in the root of a drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following example taken from [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/creating-database/) works for me. Try this out. If this doesn't work, try to create a file in your documents folder by changing the path

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error


def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_connection(r"E:\Archive.db")
```

Comment: That code will not solve the issue. It just shows the error nicely. But your suggestion of changing the folder work. I manually created a folder in E: (let's call it tempFolder). Then changed my code to create database inside tempFolder and it worked